# Set timeout for specific web methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service (.asmx) with a lot of methods.
I want to increase the timeout for one specific method, without changing the timeout of other methods.
Is it possible?

Comment: are you calling your webmethods on client side? (via ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx#scalenetchapt10_topic14) for Improving Web Services Performance - Timeouts.

It describes different approaches for defining timeouts for asynchronous and synchronous calls to a web service, on proxy, constructor and method levels.

Hope there's anything useful for you there!

**From the guide:**

**Synchronous approach**

> Or you can set it at the method level for a long-running call.

```
public string LengthyProc(int sleepTime) {
  this.Timeout = 10000; //10 seconds
  object[] results = this.Invoke("LengthyProc", new object[] {sleepTime});
  return ((string)(results[0]));  
}
```

**Asynchronous approach** - more on this approach [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/729/basics-make-any-method-call-timeoutable.aspx)

```
MyWebServ obj = new MyWebServ();
IAsyncResult ar = obj.BeginFunCall(5,5,null,null);

// wait for not more than 2 seconds
ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000,false);
if (!ar.IsCompleted) //if the request is not completed  { 
  WebClientAsyncResult wcar = (WebClientAsyncResult)ar;
  wcar.Abort();//abort the call to web service 
}
else
{ //continue processing the results from web service }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question asked here.

Comment: I think that a link to an approach on setting timeout on a web service on method level is pretty relevant in this case. But I'm sorry for not providing the final solution.

Comment: Where do you see "on method level" in there? I couldn't find it. Quote the relevant part of the guide in your post please.

Comment: I think that the link might be helpful in proving that this is not posssible to do so, but I hope to get a more definite answer. Thanks

Comment: How about [this approach](http://www.nullskull.com/a/729/basics-make-any-method-call-timeoutable.aspx) omer? Does that give you anything to work on?